# Error Compiling Qt Source

Tags: qt, compilation

I have looked all around for a solution to this problem with no avail. When compiling Qt, it runs fine for about 60 seconds until I get this and it kicks me out:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cmath:44:0,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\random:38,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h
:65,
             from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\algorithm:62,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h
:89,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qalgorithm
s.h:45,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/qalgorithms.h:1,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:
45,
             from ..\..\..\include/QtCore/qvector.h:1,
             from ..\..\..\include\QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qstack.h:4
5,
             from ..\..\..\include\QtCore/qstack.h:1,
             from parser.h:45,
             from moc.h:45,
             from moc.cpp:42:
c:\mingw\include\math.h: In function 'float hypotf(float, float)':
c:\mingw\include\math.h:635:30: error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope
 { return (float)(_hypot (x, y)); }
                          ^
Makefile.Release:307: recipe for target '.obj/release/moc.o' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [.obj/release/moc.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/QtS/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/QtS/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'sub-moc-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-moc-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/QtS/qtbase/src'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/QtS/qtbase'
Makefile:63: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2

C:\Qt\QtS>
```

I am compiling using MinGW, and this is my first experience with compiling source really so I'm stumped on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google a bit for `error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope` you will find several reports from several different projects. Looks like a MinGW bug. Not too much you can do, if this is true.

Do you really need a 32bit Qt? According to Google at least one 64bit MinGW does not have this bug.

I would try it. Perhaps you find a newer MinGW version?

http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php

EDIT:
Just found: https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW

> There are binary installers targetting MinGW for both Qt 4 and Qt 5.
>   Up to Qt 4.8.6, Qt 4 ones are built with a MinGW.org toolchain using
>   gcc 4.4. Newer Qt 4.8 binary packages ship with a mingw-w64 based
>   toolchain. **For Qt 5, a newer MinGW-w64 toolchain is actually required.**

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really didn't want to look like an idiot who doesn't know how to google but I didn't know _what_ to google. I really didn't think anything of getting 32 bit version either, as for most programs 32 bit works fine. I'll try getting the 64 bit. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, don't worry. Didn't think of you as an idiot. Being able to google is one thing, having the experience to interpret the results another. :-) If you try this version and it works, please let us know. Quite some time since I had to compile Qt5 for Windows, hope it will be quite some time till I have to do it again, but one never knows.

Comment: Also one other question, do you know what I would use for the -platform flag? win32-g++ defaults to the 32 bit one.

Comment: Not sure I set the  -platform flag. Quite some time since I compiled Qt5 on Windows. If necessary I can check tomorrow. But maybe you can spare yourself the hassle: http://tver-soft.org/qt64 and https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt64ng/

Comment: If I try building it without the platform tag, it defaults to the Microsoft C++ Compiler which crashes for some reason, and I don't even want to try to mess with that. I tried adding the new mingw64 bin folder to the PATH and using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ as the platform tag (it's in the folder), but it gives it's an invalid platform.

Comment: Ah, could not have happened to me... no Microsoft C++ compiler installed. Try win32-g++. mingw64-make should still build 64bit, mingw32-make 32bit.... If not, a bit patience, please. I have currently no access to my build machine and documentation :-)

Comment: I just tried that and it's currently compiling, been going for about 10 minutes without errors. Thanks for the help, I'm not trying to rush you at all :)

Comment: No problem. Looks like I needed the refresher. :-)

Comment: After about 15 minutes of compiling, I ended up with [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32346) error, so I guess not much I can do. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Did you try to compile static qt libs?

Comment: Yes, configured it with -static.

Comment: At least one good outcome... I finally got new incentive to try this: http://mxe.cc/

Comment: Is static necessary? How exactly did you try to compile? In the bug report it was said the error happened with msys.  I never managed to compile Qt5 with msys. You have to use Windows command line.

Comment: I used the command line directly. I'm trying to compile it static to create a standalone .exe file to share with some friends.

Comment: 'Directly' does not say anything. Can be direcly in msys terminal or in cmd.exe. :-D

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Opened cmd.exe, cd'd to the directory, and proceeded to run the commands.

Comment: In that case I am out of ideas... at least without compiling myself. I checked... the last time I compiled Qt5 for Windows it was Qt 5.1... pre-release. So.. quite some time ago. And never static.... if static makes a difference.